# Android & Java simple Code

Tags: java, android

I Wonder what is and does (this) in this code:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` refers to the current object, which is probably the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). `Activity` extends [`Context`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html), and it is passed as `Context` to the [`Button` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html#Button%28android.content.Context%29).

Comment: I see. Would it be fine if I omit (this)?

Comment: No! you need to pass the context to the Button constructor

Comment: Ok. May I write other words in parenthesis? If yes, what would they mean?

Comment: I think it is better that you explain the whole problem (in a new question) please add relevant code, and the error that you have. This way is kind of cryptic.

Comment: Oh, no, I don't program anything with Java right now. When I read such code, and I don't find explanation on it, I just wonder what it is like and what is its equivalent in Objective-C?

Comment: The equivalent in Obj-C is more-or-less `self`

Answer (score 4):

Its a reference to the [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Comment: I see. Would it be fine if I omit (this)?